# What's the most efficient way to remove first character of a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string `c1234` -- what's the most efficient and quick way to remove the first letter of a string?

Comment: Most efficient for you the programmer, or for the computer to calculate? (And if the latter...do you really care?)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `slice!`:

```
s = "Hello"
s.slice!(0) #=> "ello"
```

Try it in an `irb`:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :001 > s = "Hello"
 => "Hello" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :002 > s.slice!(0) #=> "ello"
 => "H" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :003 > s
 => "ello"
```

Comment: No, it returns "H" but removes it from s.

Answer (score 21):

Best solution is going to be `"foobar"[1..-1]`. No regex needed.

Answer (score 20):

Speaking of efficiency I never had a good chance to play with ruby's `Benchmark` module so decided to do it out of curiosity right now. Here's benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 10_000_000

s = 'c1234'

Benchmark.bm(8) do |x|
  x.report('slice!')  { n.times { s.dup.slice!(0) } }
  x.report('slice')   { n.times { s.dup.slice(1, 4) } }
  x.report('[1..-1]') { n.times { s.dup[1..-1] } }
  x.report('[1..4]')  { n.times { s.dup[1..4] } }
  x.report('reverse') { n.times { s.dup.reverse.chop.reverse } }
  x.report('gsub')    { n.times { s.dup.gsub(/^./, "") } }
  x.report('sub')     { n.times { s.dup.sub(/^./, "") } }
end
```

And there are results:

```
              user     system      total        real
slice!    7.460000   0.000000   7.460000  (7.493322)
slice     6.880000   0.000000   6.880000  (6.902811)
[1..-1]   7.710000   0.000000   7.710000  (7.728741)
[1..4]    7.700000   0.000000   7.700000  (7.717171)
reverse  10.130000   0.000000  10.130000 (10.151716)
gsub     11.030000   0.000000  11.030000 (11.051068)
sub       9.860000   0.000000   9.860000  (9.880881)
```

Seems like `slice` is the best choice with the most obvious (at least for me) `s[1..-1]` or `s[1..4]` a little behind. And solutions with `reverse` and regexp looks to complex for that kind of task.

Comment: very interesting. Maybe because it would have to look up -1 and change it to the length.

Comment: Added `[1..4]` and `slice!` versions. Funny thing: `[]` looks really slower than pure `slice`. Anyway, I'll keep using brackets version as it looks nicer to me.

Comment: +1 for benchmarking non-mutating methods. Note that `sub` might be a _hair_ faster than `gsub`, as the global nature of `gsub` is not needed here.

Comment: Ok, here it is: `sub` is really faster. Thanks for the tip, Phrogz.

Comment: Aw...and now -1 for using `dup` on non-mutating methods.

Comment: Just for the record: replacing `s = 'c1234'` with `def s; 'c1234'; end` and removing `dup` from all tests makes every one of them approximately 3 seconds faster. But it doesn't change overall picture unless we start counting percentage difference.

Comment: When benching I think it also might be useful to specify ruby version. For future people finding this post.

Comment: Did you mean `s[1...-1]` (three periods) when you wrote `s[1..-1]` in the last part of your answer?

Answer (score 14):

Option 1:

```
"abcd"[1..-1]
```

Option 2 (More descriptive):

```
"abcd".last(-1)
```

Comment: Clever.  (This isn't a very valuable comment, but this answer had no attention in a pool of many useful answers.  Because the other answers have lots of activity, I didn't feel that the single up-vote was enough to express my true appreciation for this answer - so I'm making this comment in hopes that the lack of other activity surrounding this question is less likely to dissuade people from taking the answer seriously.)

Comment: Option 2 is deprecated in Rails 6, it gives this warning: `Calling String#last with a negative integer limit will raise an ArgumentError in Rails 6.1`

Answer (score 5):

There is more than one way to do it :)

```
"foobar".gsub(/^./, "")  # => "oobar"
```

Comment: Not sure if regex would be the best way to do this. It would so much faster and efficient to just remove the first character.

Answer (score 3):

I took the solutions up to now and cretaed a benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'

#~ TEST_LOOPS = 10_000_000
TEST_LOOPS = 10_000
TESTSTRING = 'Hello'

Benchmark.bmbm(10) {|b|

  b.report('slice!') {    
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      s = TESTSTRING.dup
      s.slice!(0)
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  b.report('gsub^') {    
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      s = TESTSTRING.dup
      s.gsub(/^./, "")
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report


  b.report('gsub\A') {    
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      s = TESTSTRING.dup
      s.gsub(/\A./, "")
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  b.report('[1..-1]') {    
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      s = TESTSTRING.dup
      s = s[1..-1]
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  b.report('s[0] = ""') {    
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      s = TESTSTRING.dup
      s[0] = ''
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  b.report('reverse.chop') {    
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      s = TESTSTRING.dup
      s = s.reverse.chop.reverse
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report
} #Benchmark
```

Result:

```
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------------
slice!         0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000000)
gsub^          0.063000   0.000000   0.063000 (  0.062500)
gsub\A         0.031000   0.000000   0.031000 (  0.031250)
[1..-1]        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000000)
s[0] = ""      0.015000   0.000000   0.015000 (  0.015625)
reverse.chop   0.016000   0.000000   0.016000 (  0.015625)
--------------------------------------- total: 0.125000sec

                   user     system      total        real
slice!         0.016000   0.000000   0.016000 (  0.015625)
gsub^          0.046000   0.000000   0.046000 (  0.046875)
gsub\A         0.032000   0.000000   0.032000 (  0.031250)
[1..-1]        0.015000   0.000000   0.015000 (  0.015625)
s[0] = ""      0.016000   0.000000   0.016000 (  0.015625)
reverse.chop   0.016000   0.000000   0.016000 (  0.015625)
```

At least the regular expresions should not be used.

Comment: You're calling `dup` 10s of thousands of times unnecessarily on the non-mutating methods.

Comment: I think calling `dup` in all tests is a good idea. You can't go without it in `slice!` test, but removing it from other tests will make them looking much faster than this one.

Comment: @KL-7 But adding in a `dup` artificially slows down the non-mutating methods, as they are _already_ creating a new copy of the string.

Comment: I wanted an easy way to define my test string. So I defined a constant and created my teststring always in the same way with dup. So each testcase starts with the same string and the same time to create the test string. As an alternative I could start always with a fix string.

Comment: @Phrogz, I still can't agree. We're just adding the same penalty to all tests allowing them to share string `s`. So no one really get slower because of this `dup` as it occurs in all of them. Alternatively we can remove `dup` from all tests, but in that case we'll have to pass string literal instead of variable in every one of them (otherwise `slice!` will ruin it after first iteration). But dealing with single variable is much more pleasant than with 6 identical string literals.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ruby 1.9:

```
s = "foobar"
s[0] = ''
```